# ACPI error preventing boot after kernel update

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi

not certain if this is a generic Linux query or an Ubuntu query, but here goes.

I have a Z800 workstation, which was running Xubuntu 18.04, with kernel 4.15 . It's a dual processor machine. It has the latest BIOS available for this machine ( 3.61, from some time last year ).

I just applied a batch of updates. Now my machine will not boot. The error is :

```
ACPI Error: [CAPD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dsfield-212)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO._OSC, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/psparse-550)
```

I have read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/ACPITricksAndTips, and
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093882/unable-to-boot-after-installation-acpi-errors, and many other things, and am suitably horrified by the mess that is ACPI, but would still really like my machine to work again.

I have tried many combinations of kernel parameters. Using '`acpi=off`' results in a kernel panic. All the other variations I have tried of the many acpi related options ( including `acpi=ht`, and specifying the `acpi_serialize` option ) gives the same result as given above.

This occurs *no matter which 4.15 kernel I try to start, not just the latest one*. I have several historical 4.15 kernels, one of which I was using prior to this update, and yet now they all give this error. I also have an ancient 4.4 kernel, which does not give this error, but hangs before starting my desktop - but that's no great surpise.

I would love to be able to revert the BIOS just to see what effect that had, but the HP site doesn't seem to list historical versions.

So I think what I don't understand is what can an update change which would affect the ACPI behaviour of any 4.15 kernel, including those that previously worked ? If there's some other list that would be more suitable for this query, feel free to redirect me.

Comment: Assuming the "batch of updates" includes a BIOS update: The ACPI tables are part of the BIOS, and it's a known problem that vendors are sloppy and don't follow the standard, which causes trouble when Linux follows the standard and tries to interpret the tables. I'd take this to the ACPI kernel developer mailing list or bug tracker, and ask them if they can think of a workaround.

Comment: Thankyou for the mailing list suggestion. The BIOS version did not appear to change after the updates - it's still the version I loaded last year. It's an old machine, the manufacturer does not appear to be supporting it via fwupd.